# How to initialize a modal dialog ? (C++ / MFC)

Tags: c++, mfc, modal-dialog

I would like to fill some fields of my dialog when it's shown. Consequently, I would like to follow those steps:

1. construct the dialog object
2. call DoModal()
3. initialize its fields

However, I can pass to the instruction following DoModal() only when the dialog is closed. Consequently, how can I initialize my dialog's fields?

I tried to override DoModal():

```
int MyDialog::DoModal()
{
    int a = CDialogEx::DoModal();
    InitDialog();

    return a;
}
```

but it's the same issue: InitDialog() is called when the dialog is closed...

Comment: DoModal does not return until the dialog is dismissed.  Instantiate MyDialog, initialize the members, THEN call DoModal()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the dialog object, than add `OnInitDialog` on your dialog, this method will calls before showing dialog ([OnInitDialog msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fwz35s59(v=vs.110).aspx)).
Add variables to your dialog (int a;)

Call dailog:

```
CDialog dlg;
dlg.a = 10;
dlg.DoModal();
```

Comment: Thanks! That was the solution :)

Comment: Initialization should be done by a constructor instead of making a member variable public (= bad design).

Comment: By default there are only default constructor, you need override it

Comment: Or add public methods which pass values in as parameters which then get assigned to your variables.